How to evaluate estimation of treatment effect under wrong linear model ignoring replicated measurements?
A Simulation study with the following task is given:
Do 1000 simulation runs based on simulated data from the model below to explore the following issue:
How well is the coefficient of $x_1$ (treatment effect) estimated by the simple linear model, ignoring the fact that there are replicate measurements ($y \sim x_1 + x_2)$?
Variables:

$y$: outcome of clinical study (effect of medication)
indiv individuals = 20
repl replicate measurements per individual taken on consecutive days after the treatment = 10
explanatory variables:
- $x_1$ ... the treatment (2 treatments) - half of the individuals receive treatment/placebo
- $x_2$ ... the time of measurement (in days, 1...10 (continuous predictor))
- $x_3$ ... indicator coding the individual

Underlying model: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \gamma_1(x_3) + \gamma_2(x_3)*x_2 + \epsilon$
Furthermore $\beta_0 = 1$, $\beta_1 = 1$, $\beta_2 = 0.5$, $\gamma_1(x_3) \sim N(0,4)$ i.i.d., $\gamma_2(x_3) \sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d., $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d.
I came up with the following code:
library(lmerTest)

Data generation process
sim.data <- function(indiv,repl,param.beta,param.gamma.1,param.gamma.2,param.eps) {
  
  indiv <- indiv          # number of individuals / people
  repl <- repl            # number of replications (= number of measurements) per individual
  
  b.0 <- param.beta[1]    # betas fixed effects
  b.1 <-  param.beta[2]
  b.2 <-  param.beta[3]
  
  x.1 <- rep(rep(0:1,each=repl),length.out=indiv*repl)  # Treatment: no,yes
  x.2 <- rep(1:10,length.out=indiv*repl)                # day of treatment per individual
  id <- rep(1:indiv,each=repl)                          # indicator coding the individual = x.3
  
  gamma.1 <- rnorm(indiv,mean=param.gamma.1[1],sd=param.gamma.1[2])
  gamma.2 <- rnorm(indiv,mean=param.gamma.2[1],sd=param.gamma.2[2])
  
  g1 <- gamma.1[id]   # intercept random effects
  g2 <- gamma.2[id]   # slope random effects
  
  e <- rnorm(length(x.1),mean=param.eps[1],sd=param.eps[2])
  
  y <- b.0 + b.1*x.1 + b.2*x.2 + g1 + g2*x.2 + e
  
  data.sim <- data.frame(x.1 = x.1,
                         x.2 = x.2,
                         x.3 = id,
                         y = y)
  
  return(data.sim)
  
}

set.seed(11525)
data <- sim.data(20,10,c(1,1,0.5),c(0,4),c(0,1),c(0,1))

true.mod <- lmer(y ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1 + x.2||x.3), REML = FALSE, data = data)    

summary(true.mod)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: y ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1 + x.2 || x.3)
   Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   786.7    806.5   -387.4    774.7      194 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6798 -0.5763 -0.0162  0.5099  2.3082 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 x.3      (Intercept) 19.148   4.3758  
 x.3.1    x.2          0.624   0.7899  
 Residual              1.149   1.0720  
Number of obs: 200, groups:  x.3, 20

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   1.0620     1.4028 20.0049   0.757  0.45784   
x.1           1.0050     1.9837 19.9957   0.507  0.61797   
x.2           0.5180     0.1786 20.0132   2.900  0.00884 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr) x.1   
x.1 -0.707       
x.2 -0.015  0.000

Simulation
# set amount of simulation runs
n.sim <- 1000

mod.lin.b.1 <- function(y,x.1,x.2) {
  mod <- lm(y ~ x.1 + x.2)
  return(mod)
}

# simulation
beta.1.lin <- numeric(length=length(n.sim))
beta.1.sign.lin <- numeric(length=length(n.sim))

set.seed(1234)

for (i in 1:n.sim) {
    y.sim <- unlist(simulate(true.mod))
    sim.mod <- mod.lin.b.1(y=y.sim,data$x.1,data$x.2)
    beta.1.lin[i] <- summary(sim.mod)$coefficients[2,1]
beta.1.sign.lin[i] <- summary(sim.mod)$coefficients[2,4]    
}

# findings:
summary(beta.1.lin)

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-8.3407 -1.0379  0.9543  0.8276  2.6926 10.3577 

mean(beta.1.lin[beta.1.sign.lin < 0.05])

[1] 1.367032

mean(beta.1.sign.lin<0.05)   # power of model

[1] 0.552

Description of findings:
The treatment effect of $x_1$ is, including all $\beta_1$, on average estimated close to the true parameter. Looking at the mean of the significant parameters, the treatment effect was overestimated. In around half the cases $\beta_1$ was significant.
Question:
To answer the task, I checked the significance and estimation of the effect. Is the simulation technically correct (usage of simulate())? Why is $\beta_1$ overestimated? How to evaluate the power for this model?
Any help is really appreciated!

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read & follow the tag instructions.

Re: your title: you can, in my understanding, use model comparison anova to compare a multilevel model to a single-level model.

Thanks for your suggestion Sointu! I will adapt the title. I think it's misleading. It's about evaluating how well a coefficient is estimated (under the wrong model compared to the true model).
